# How can I make Custom UIButton with image and text?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

As I did on Android under a layout arrange an ImageView and TextView and set ClickListener on Layout so same thing how can I do on `swift (3.0) Xcode 8`. 
There is no markup like XML. It's difficult to do with drag and drop.

How can I make this view with responsive for all device screens.

My UI image is below:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

after using CollectionView it shows like this

[image]

Comment: use UICollectionView and create your custom cell, if you want it in uibutton, use titleInset and image inset, to all screen use auto layout

Comment: You may use an image view and label to display an image and text . Then place an UIButton over that without any text/image. Place these UI elements inside a UICollection cell.

Comment: I have only 3 item like this and under those three items have put another item horizontal scrolling any suggestion ?

Comment: Use UICollectionView for horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code to set image and title to button

```
let imageSize: CGSize = button.imageView!.image!.size
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(26 , -imageSize.width, 0.0, 0.0);
let labelString = NSString(string: button.titleLabel!.text!)
let titleSize = labelString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: button.titleLabel!.font])
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-15, 0.0, 0.0, -titleSize.width);
```

Comment: in where or which file and specific which method I'm new in swift .

Comment: Create a method with button as parameter. After setting image and title to the button, pass that button to the created method.

Answer (score 1):

You can set UIImage + UIText inside UIButton , for reference 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton